# How to connect to device and log the details of Bluetooth LE Scan as soon as advertising device is found?

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am making an app that has both a scanning and advertising functionality as I want to conduct some BLE experiments. But most of the time during the scan I get the device name and UUID as `null` and there are just flashes for when I am able to see the device that I am advertising with.

The scan feature works fine when I use an app like LightBlue because it constantly shows up in the scan window and the advertisement feature also seems to work fine when I start a scan using the LightBlue app so it is confusing me about what is causing the problem.

I want the scanning feature to detect the device as fast as it can, connect to it and return the details like timestamp, RSSI value etc. of the signal so I can use those values for my experiment. What changes should I do to my following code in order to do that with accuracy?

Here is the advertisement code:

```
final BluetoothManager bluetoothManagerAdv = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService( Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);

        if (bluetoothManagerAdv != null) {
             mBluetoothAdapterAdv = bluetoothManagerAdv.getAdapter();
        }
        mBluetoothAdapterAdv.setName ( "BLE Experiment" );

        mBluetoothLeAdvertiser = mBluetoothAdapterAdv.getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();

        AdvertisingSetParameters parameters = new AdvertisingSetParameters.Builder().setInterval(AdvertisingSetParameters.INTERVAL_HIGH).setTxPowerLevel(AdvertisingSetParameters.TX_POWER_HIGH)
                        .setConnectable(true).build();

        AdvertiseData data = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
                .setIncludeDeviceName(false)
                .build();

        mAdvertiseCallback = new AdvertisingSetCallback () {

            @Override
            public void onAdvertisingSetStarted(AdvertisingSet advertisingSet,
                                                int txPower,
                                                int status) {
                super.onAdvertisingSetStarted (advertisingSet, txPower, status);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdvertisingSetStopped(AdvertisingSet advertisingSet) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Advertising onStartFailure: ");
                super.onAdvertisingSetStopped (advertisingSet);
            }
        };

        mBluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertisingSet(parameters, data, null,null,null, mAdvertiseCallback);
```

And the scan code:

```
mIsScanning = true;
            ScanSettings.Builder builderScanSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder();
            builderScanSettings.setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_BALANCED);

            mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(null, builderScanSettings.build(), scanCallback);

        } else {

            enableScanBtn();
            mIsScanning = false;
            mBluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(scanCallback);
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private final ScanCallback scanCallback = new ScanCallback () {


        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {

            super.onScanResult ( callbackType, result );


            if (mList.size () > 0) {
                try {
                    mList.clear ();
                    mArrayAdapter.clear ();
                    mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();
                    rssi = result.getRssi ();
                    id = Arrays.toString(result.getDevice ().getUuids ());
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                }
            }

            if (result == null || result.getDevice () == null) {
                Log.e ( TAG, "-> No devices found" );
                return;
            }

            try {


                name = result.getDevice ().getName ();


                time= System.currentTimeMillis();


                String apDetails = "AP: " + name + "\n" +
                        "UUID: " + id + "\n" +
                        "RSSI: " + rssi + "\n" +
                        "Time : " + time;

                Log.i ( TAG, apDetails );

                mList.add ( apDetails );

            } catch (NullPointerException e) {

                Log.e ( TAG, e.getMessage () );
            }

            mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<> ( getApplicationContext (),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mList );
            mListView.setAdapter ( mArrayAdapter );
```

If you want to see the complete code in the activity : [here is the link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ThQ36202kM5HtX4fru1GeMna6z-m9S8EqszfBCGtapQ/edit?usp=sharing)